# Add couple DIVs with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a short paragraph ending with the phrase "FIND OUT MORE".

So `onclick` I want to add some text with pictures to that `div`.

Here's what I'm doing, this is my JS:

```
function appendText() {
    var txt = '<div class="accomodations">
                    <h3>Одноместный номер</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="img/living1-1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/living1-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/living1-3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                    </ul>   
                    <p>Стоимость: 3000грн/заезд</p>
                </div>

                <div class="accomodations">
                    <h3>Двуместный номер</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="img/living2-1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/living2-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/living2-3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>Стоимость: 2500грн/заезд</p>
                </div>

                <div class="accomodations">
                    <h3>Трехместный номер</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="img/living3-1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/living3-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/living3-3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>Стоимость: 2000грн/заезд</p>
                </div>'';'

    $("#livingbg").append(txt);
}
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<a href="" onclick="appendText()">Find out more...</a>
```

Comment: So is this a demonstration of the code or a question?

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: it doesn't work :). That was the demonstration of what i did, but it didn't work. So the Q is - what's wrong

Comment: `It doesn't work` don't seems the be an appropriate way of describing an error.

Comment: Make sure to also check the console, it can give you details on what the problem is. In this case it will be `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal`, meaning there is a problem with how the string is made (it was never closed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multi-line strings you need to add `\` to the end of each line:

```
var txt = '<div class="accomodations">\
                <h3>Одноместный номер</h3>\
                <ul>\
                    <li><img src="img/living1-1.jpg" alt=""></li>\
                    <li><img src="img/living1-2.jpg" alt=""></li>\
                    <li><img src="img/living1-3.jpg" alt=""></li>\
                </ul>   \
                <p>Стоимость: 3000грн/заезд</p>\
            </div>\
\
            <div class="accomodations">\
                <h3>Двуместный номер</h3>\
                <ul>\
                    <li><img src="img/living2-1.jpg" alt=""></li>\
                    <li><img src="img/living2-2.jpg" alt=""></li>\
                    <li><img src="img/living2-3.jpg" alt=""></li>\
                </ul>\
                <p>Стоимость: 2500грн/заезд</p>\
            </div>\
\
            <div class="accomodations">\
                <h3>Трехместный номер</h3>\
                <ul>\
                    <li><img src="img/living3-1.jpg" alt=""></li>\
                    <li><img src="img/living3-2.jpg" alt=""></li>\
                    <li><img src="img/living3-3.jpg" alt=""></li>\
                </ul>\
                <p>Стоимость: 2000грн/заезд</p>\
            </div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function appendText() {
var txt = '<div class="accomodations">'+
                '<h3>Одноместный номер</h3>'+
                '<ul>'+
                    '<li><img src="img/living1-1.jpg" alt=""></li>'+
                    '<li><img src="img/living1-2.jpg" alt=""></li>'+
                    '<li><img src="img/living1-3.jpg" alt=""></li>'+
                '</ul>'+   
                '<p>Стоимость: 3000грн/заезд</p>'+
            '</div>'+

            '<div class="accomodations">'+
                '<h3>Двуместный номер</h3>'+
                '<ul>'+
                    '<li><img src="img/living2-1.jpg" alt=""></li>'+
                    '<li><img src="img/living2-2.jpg" alt=""></li>'+
                    '<li><img src="img/living2-3.jpg" alt=""></li>'+
                '</ul>'+
                '<p>Стоимость: 2500грн/заезд</p>'+
            '</div>'+

            '<div class="accomodations">'+
                '<h3>Трехместный номер</h3>'+
                '<ul>'+
                    '<li><img src="img/living3-1.jpg" alt=""></li>'+
                    '<li><img src="img/living3-2.jpg" alt=""></li>'+
                    '<li><img src="img/living3-3.jpg" alt=""></li>'+
                '</ul>'+
                '<p>Стоимость: 2000грн/заезд</p>'+
            '</div>';

    $("#livingbg").append(txt);
}
```

Using this way would make the code understand much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
function Convert(f) {
    return f.toString().
        replace(/^[^\/]+\/\*!?/, '').
        replace(/\*\/[^\/]+$/, '');
}

var sample=Convert(function() {/* Add what ever you want here */})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wrhjj04f/

In this way you are not worry about any thing quotes, double quotes, new line ... , just put your text around a comment.

---

```
 function Convert(f) {
        return f.toString().
            replace(/^[^\/]+\/\*!?/, '').
            replace(/\*\/[^\/]+$/, '');
    }

    var sample=Convert(function() {/*
    <div class="accomodations">
                    <h3>Одноместный номер</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="img/living1-1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/living1-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/living1-3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                    </ul>   
                    <p>Стоимость: 3000грн/заезд</p>
                </div>

                <div class="accomodations">
                    <h3>Двуместный номер</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="img/living2-1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/living2-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/living2-3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>Стоимость: 2500грн/заезд</p>
                </div>

                <div class="accomodations">
                    <h3>Трехместный номер</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="img/living3-1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/living3-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                        <li><img src="img/living3-3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>Стоимость: 2000грн/заезд</p>
                </div>

 */})

                       alert(sample);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function appendText(e) {
    var strVar = "";
    strVar += "<div class=\"accomodations\">";
    strVar += "                    <h3>Одноместный номер<\/h3>";
    strVar += "                    <ul>";
    strVar += "                        <li><img src=\"img\/living1-1.jpg\" alt=\"\"><\/li>";
    strVar += "                        <li><img src=\"img\/living1-2.jpg\" alt=\"\"><\/li>";
    strVar += "                        <li><img src=\"img\/living1-3.jpg\" alt=\"\"><\/li>";
    strVar += "                    <\/ul>   ";
    strVar += "                    <p>Стоимость: 3000грн\/заезд<\/p>";
    strVar += "                <\/div>";
    strVar += "";
    strVar += "                <div class=\"accomodations\">";
    strVar += "                    <h3>Двуместный номер<\/h3>";
    strVar += "                    <ul>";
    strVar += "                        <li><img src=\"img\/living2-1.jpg\" alt=\"\"><\/li>";
    strVar += "                        <li><img src=\"img\/living2-2.jpg\" alt=\"\"><\/li>";
    strVar += "                        <li><img src=\"img\/living2-3.jpg\" alt=\"\"><\/li>";
    strVar += "                    <\/ul>";
    strVar += "                    <p>Стоимость: 2500грн\/заезд<\/p>";
    strVar += "                <\/div>";
    strVar += "";
    strVar += "                <div class=\"accomodations\">";
    strVar += "                    <h3>Трехместный номер<\/h3>";
    strVar += "                    <ul>";
    strVar += "                        <li><img src=\"img\/living3-1.jpg\" alt=\"\"><\/li>";
    strVar += "                        <li><img src=\"img\/living3-2.jpg\" alt=\"\"><\/li>";
    strVar += "                        <li><img src=\"img\/living3-3.jpg\" alt=\"\"><\/li>";
    strVar += "                    <\/ul>";
    strVar += "                    <p>Стоимость: 2000грн\/заезд<\/p>";
    strVar += "                <\/div>";

    $("#livingbg").append(strVar);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onClick="appendText();">Find out more...</a>

<div id="livingbg"><div>
```

**HTML JS convert helper** : http://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/